# Calculate date difference in sql for specific year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two dates, say start_date is 20141215 and end_date = 20150115. I would like to use SQL DATEDIFF to only count the dates within the year 2015 which I will specify in the query. Here is the current SQL I have written:

```
SELECT COUNT(leave_id), 
    sum(case when leave_status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) pending, 
    sum(case when leave_status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) declined, 
    sum(case when leave_status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) approved,
    sum(case when leave_status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) rostered,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date)+1) as datetotals
    FROM employee_leave WHERE 
    ((YEAR(start_date) = :year) OR (YEAR(end_date) = :year)) 
    AND employee_id = :emp_id
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix `datediff()` to only consider dates during the year.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(leave_id), 
       sum(case when leave_status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) pending, 
       sum(case when leave_status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) declined, 
       sum(case when leave_status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) approved,
       sum(case when leave_status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) rostered,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(least(end_date, date(concat_ws('-', :year, 12, 31))),
                    greatest(start_date, date(concat_ws('-', :year, 1, 1)))
                   ) + 1) as datetotals
FROM employee_leave 
WHERE ((YEAR(start_date) = :year) OR (YEAR(end_date) = :year)) AND
      employee_id = :emp_id
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this works perfectly for what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a `AND` condition rather like

```
WHERE 
    ((YEAR(start_date) = :year) AND (YEAR(end_date) = :year))
```